# SBS 2008 SharePoint Incoming E-Mail - DNS issue?

Tags: domain-name-system, sharepoint, exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008

I have an SBS 2008 box with Exchange 2007 and Sharepoint 2007. I am trying to configure a SharePoint site Document Library to accept incoming e-mail. I've left SharePoint set up with the default "companyweb" name. I enable incoming e-mail on the document library with "foo@companyweb" as the address. I've configured I've used [this link](http://blogs.technet.com/sbs/archive/2009/02/02/how-to-use-outlook-to-send-email-to-a-sharepoint-document-library-on-sbs-2008.aspx) to allow Outlook to send mail to the "foo@companyweb" address.

When I send e-mail to the address I'm finding it stuck in the Exchange Queue Viewer. Next Hop Domain "companyweb" Delivery Type "DnsConnectorDelivery" Error "451 4.4.0 DNS query failed".

"companyweb" has a CNAME alias to the SBS server in DNS. I've tried flushing the cache, still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're missing the SMTP connector in Exchange. That'd get you in the loop you're now describing. You'd create a new connector (New->SMTP Connector), and set it up (roughly) like this:

forward all mail through this connector... : companyweb IP

Address space:
Add "companyweb"
type=SMTP
cost=1
connector scope=routing group
check "Allow messages to be relayed..."

You'll now have two connectors. Edit your internet smtp connector and give it a higher cost than 1. Now, exchange should check the connector for *@companyweb mail first, and then check the internet connector. If you don't change the cost, you'll likely get intermittent delivery.

Comment: I'm the PM for incoming mail in SharePoint - this is what I'd guess too

Answer (score 0):

Is there a DNS zone and MX record for companyweb on the SBS server (I'm guessing not)? I don't know anything about how SBS works, but in a typical environment the email server needs to perform a DNS lookup for the MX record of the recipient domain. For the internal AD DNS zone, Exchange doesn't need an MX record so if your internal AD DNS zone is companyweb, then disregard my answer. If your internal AD DNS zone is not companyweb, then you need to create  a zone for it and create an MX record that points to the SBS server.

Comment: Creating a DNS zone for Companyweb and adding an MX record pointing to the SBS server caused all of the pending messages to bounce with "#554 5.4.4 SMTPSEND.DNS.MxLoopback; DNS records for this domain are configured in a loop ##"

Answer (score 0):

OK, sorry about that. My point here is that the email address for the contact is foo@companyweb and the Exchange server has to be able to resolve an MX record for companyweb since companyweb is an "external" domain (unless I'm thinking about this all wrong). What about creating an A record for companyweb that resolves to the SBS server?

On second thought, think about this for a minute: A user sends an email to foo@companyweb (which needs to go to sharepoint), the email goes to Exchange and Exchange sees that it's an external recipient (contact) and tries to resolve the MX record, which it can't so the emails eventually expire. creating an MX or A record for companyweb will both result in a loop because Sharepoint and Exchange are on the same server, so with an A or MX record Exchange would just keep sending the message to itself (looping). You're in a situation where companyweb, for all intents and purposes, is an external domain but the server that hosts Exchange and Sharepoint is the same server. I'm not sure how this works in a typical SBS configuration. Sorry to have lead you down the wrong path. If I think of anything else I'll post back.